# Window Manager :WIN DEATH: Window{40c12c30 com.example.trackme/com.example.trackme.MainActivity paused=false}

Tags: android, android-intent, gps

**Description** : I am developing **LBS** App, I am using GPS and Network provider  to access location and sending the data vai GPRS to server. I want to run this app continuously to locate the user.Everything is running perfectly only prob is when my app goes in background .

**Problem**: My App is Running correctly when it will be in the foreground, But I want this app shd run in background , When i press the home button while running the app , I am getting this Error message . following is my MainActivity and Mylocationlistener class.

**MainActivity**:-

```
package com.example.trackme;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button start;

    private static final int TEN_SECONDS = 10000;
    private static final int TEN_METERS = 10;
    private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;
    private boolean mGeocoderAvailable;
    private String addressText;
    LocationManager mlocManager ;
     LocationListener mlocListener=new MyLocationListener("", "");

    private String device_ID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         mGeocoderAvailable =Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD && Geocoder.isPresent();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {



            }
        });
    }



    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setup();
    }
    private void setup() {
         Location gpsLocation = null;
            Location networkLocation = null;


            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            device_ID=telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

            mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
                gpsLocation = requestUpdatesFromProvider(
                     LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                networkLocation = requestUpdatesFromProvider(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                // Update the UI immediately if a location is obtained.

                // If both providers return last known locations, compare the two and use the better
                // one to update the UI.  If only one provider returns a location, use it.
                if (gpsLocation != null && networkLocation != null) {
                    updateUILocation(getBetterLocation(gpsLocation, networkLocation));
                } else if (gpsLocation != null) {
                    updateUILocation(gpsLocation);
                } else if (networkLocation != null) {
                    updateUILocation(networkLocation);


    }
}



                private void doReverseGeocoding(Location location) {
                    // Since the geocoding API is synchronous and may take a while.  You don't want to lock
                    // up the UI thread.  Invoking reverse geocoding in an AsyncTask.
                    (new ReverseGeocodingTask(this)).execute(new Location[] {location});
                      mlocListener = new MyLocationListener(addressText,device_ID); 
                }

                private void updateUILocation(Location location) {
                    // We're sending the update to a handler which then updates the UI with the new
                    // location.
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),location.getProvider()+ ","+ location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    if (mGeocoderAvailable) doReverseGeocoding(location);
                }

                protected Location getBetterLocation(Location newLocation, Location currentBestLocation) {
                    if (currentBestLocation == null) {
                        // A new location is always better than no location
                        return newLocation;
                    }

                    // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
                    long timeDelta = newLocation.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
                    boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
                    boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
                    boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

                    // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
                    // because the user has likely moved.
                    if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
                        System.out.println("Provider"+newLocation.getProvider());
                        return newLocation;
                    // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
                    } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
                        System.out.println("Provider"+currentBestLocation.getProvider());
                        return currentBestLocation;
                    }

                    // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
                    int accuracyDelta = (int) (newLocation.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
                    boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
                    boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
                    boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

                    // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
                    boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(newLocation.getProvider(),
                            currentBestLocation.getProvider());

                    // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
                    if (isMoreAccurate) {
                        System.out.println("Provider"+newLocation.getProvider());
                        return newLocation;

                    } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
                         System.out.println("Provider"+newLocation.getProvider());
                        return newLocation;

                    } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
                         System.out.println("Provider"+newLocation.getProvider());
                        return newLocation;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Provider"+currentBestLocation.getProvider());
                    return currentBestLocation;


                }

                private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
                    if (provider1 == null) {
                      return provider2 == null;
                    }
                    return provider1.equals(provider2);
                }

    private Location requestUpdatesFromProvider(String provider) {
        Location location = null;

        if (mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
            mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, TEN_SECONDS, TEN_METERS, mlocListener);
            location = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        } else {
          //  Toast.makeText(this, errorResId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return location;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

         mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        final boolean gpsEnabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); 


        if (!gpsEnabled) {
            // Build an alert dialog here that requests that the user enable
            // the location services, then when the user clicks the "OK" button,
            // call enableLocationSettings()

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pls Enable GPS" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}





private class ReverseGeocodingTask extends AsyncTask<Location, Void, Void> {
    Context mContext;


    public ReverseGeocodingTask(Context context) {
        super();
        mContext = context;

           }





    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Location... params) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());

        Location loc = params[0];
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Update address field with the exception.

            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            // Format the first line of address (if available), city, and country name.
             addressText = String.format("%s, %s, %s",
                    address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                    address.getLocality(),
                    address.getCountryName());
            // Update address field on UI.
           // Message.obtain(mHandler, UPDATE_ADDRESS, addressText).sendToTarget();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), addressText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println(addressText);




        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

**Mylocationlistener**:-

```
package com.example.trackme;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyLocationListener extends Service implements android.location.LocationListener {




    private static String device_ID;
    private float mySpeed;
    private Object time;
    private String lat;
    private String longitude;
    private int level;

    private String locate;


    public MyLocationListener(String addressText,String Device_id) {
        locate=addressText;
        MyLocationListener.device_ID=Device_id;
    }




    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {




        lat= String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude());

        longitude=String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude());


        if((lat!=null) && (longitude!=null))
        {


              String Text = "My current location is: " +

              "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +

              "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();

            //  Toast.makeText(this, Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


          //  Send.performClick();
              AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
                String sleepTime = "2000";

                if(loc.hasSpeed()){ 

                    mySpeed =  (float) (3.6 * (loc.getSpeed())); 
                   //  System.out.println("\nCurrent speed: " + mySpeed + " km/h"); 
                }

                runner.execute(sleepTime);
            Log.d("Location Found", Text);
        }



    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Provider is Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Provider is Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    private BroadcastReceiver batteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //  int  health= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH,0);
        //  int  voltage= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE,0);
             level= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,0);

            System.out.println( "Level" +level);
        }
    };


    private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

          private String resp;


          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           publishProgress("Sleeping..."); // Calls onProgressUpdate()
           try {
            // Do your long operations here and return the result
            int time = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);


            // Sleeping for given time period
            Thread.sleep(time);

           HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            String postURL = "";

             postURL = "http://smpl.trackfleet.biz/lat_long.php?lat="+lat+"&long="+longitude+"&speed="+mySpeed +"&IMEI_NO="+MyLocationListener.device_ID+"&battery_level="+level +"&location="+locate;

            //postURL = "http://bb.trackfleet.biz/android_gps/lat_long.php?lat="+lat+"&long="+longitude+"&speed=0" +"&IMEI_NO=911223100301734"+"&battery_level="+level;
                    System.out.println(postURL);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postURL);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            try
            {
        //      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sending location to Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("Sending to server");
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost); 

                String str = inputStreamToString(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
                System.out.println("Response"+str);
            //  location_sms="Sales Person="+str+"latitude="+lat+"longitude="+longitude+"&speed="+mySpeed +"&IMEI_NO="+device_ID+"&battery_level="+level +"&location="+addressText;
                // getSharedPreferences("Values", 4).edit().putString("location_sms",location_sms).commit();

            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not communicate with Server" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                System.out.println("Could not communicate with Server");
ex.printStackTrace();
            }





           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            resp = e.getMessage();
           } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            resp = e.getMessage();
           }
           return resp;
          }



        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
          String line = "";
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    // Read response until the end
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
            total.append(line); 
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Return full string
    return total;
}
    }

    }
```

**LogCat** :-

```
 WIN DEATH: Window{40c12c30 com.example.trackme/com.example.trackme.MainActivity paused=false}
02-18 13:16:45.939: I/SurfaceFlinger(201):                                                                              
02-18 13:16:45.939: I/SurfaceFlinger(201): surface flinger stars handleComposing3DStateSetting enter
02-18 13:16:45.939: I/SurfaceFlinger(201): surface flinger stars handleComposing3DStateSetting exit: 0
02-18 13:16:45.940: I/SurfaceFlinger(201):                                                                              
02-18 13:16:45.940: I/SurfaceFlinger(201): surface flinger stars handleComposing3DStateSetting enter
02-18 13:16:45.940: I/SurfaceFlinger(201): surface flinger stars handleComposing3DStateSetting exit: 0
02-18 13:16:45.942: D/IPCThreadState(201): [DN #5] BR_DEAD_BINDER cookie 0x3b5c08
02-18 13:16:45.942: D/IPCThreadState(201): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x3b5c08
02-18 13:16:45.942: D/IPCThreadState(201): [DN #5] BR_DEAD_BINDER cookie 0x20ce78
02-18 13:16:45.942: V/LocationManagerService(201): Location listener died
02-18 13:16:45.942: D/IPCThreadState(201): [DN #5] BR_DEAD_BINDER cookie 0x5ba5d8
02-18 13:16:45.943: V/ActivityManager(201): Death received in com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AppDeathRecipient@40945b90 for thread android.os.BinderProxy@40a29e30
02-18 13:16:45.943: I/ActivityManager(201): Process com.example.trackme (pid 26976) has died.
02-18 13:16:45.943: V/ActivityManager(201): Dying app: ProcessRecord{408e7ae8 26976:com.example.trackme/10067}, pid: 26976, thread: android.os.BinderProxy@40a29e30
02-18 13:16:45.943: V/ActivityManager(201): Removing app ProcessRecord{408e7ae8 0:com.example.trackme/10067} from list [HistoryRecord{40a61240 com.android.phone/.InCallScreen}, HistoryRecord{4077ea58 com.example.trackme/.MainActivity}, HistoryRecord{40875438 com.android.mlabs/.Launcher}, HistoryRecord{409808e8 com.android.settings/.SettingsTabActivity}, HistoryRecord{40adb610 com.android.settings/.ApplicationSettings}, HistoryRecord{4093d3a0 com.android.settings/.ManageApplications}] with 6 entries
02-18 13:16:45.943: V/ActivityManager(201): Record #5 HistoryRecord{4093d3a0 com.android.settings/.ManageApplications}: app=ProcessRecord{40c1f9e8 26810:com.android.settings/1000}
02-18 13:16:45.943: V/ActivityManager(201): Record #4 HistoryRecord{40adb610 com.android.settings/.ApplicationSettings}: app=ProcessRecord{40c1f9e8 26810:com.android.settings/1000}
02-18 13:16:45.943: V/ActivityManager(201): Record #3 HistoryRecord{409808e8 com.android.settings/.SettingsTabActivity}: app=ProcessRecord{40c1f9e8 26810:com.android.settings/1000}
02-18 13:16:45.943: V/ActivityManager(201): Record #2 HistoryRecord{40875438 com.android.mlabs/.Launcher}: app=ProcessRecord{407ef4e8 23796:android.process.acore/10036}
02-18 13:16:45.943: V/ActivityManager(201): Record #1 HistoryRecord{4077ea58 com.example.trackme/.MainActivity}: app=ProcessRecord{408e7ae8 0:com.example.trackme/10067}
02-18 13:16:45.943: V/ActivityManager(201): Removing this entry!
02-18 13:16:45.943: V/ActivityManager(201): Record #0 HistoryRecord{40a61240 com.android.phone/.InCallScreen}: app=ProcessRecord{40881af0 289:com.android.phone/1001}
02-18 13:16:45.943: V/ActivityManager(201): Removing app ProcessRecord{408e7ae8 0:com.example.trackme/10067} from list [] with 0 entries
02-18 13:16:45.943: V/ActivityManager(201): Removing app ProcessRecord{408e7ae8 0:com.example.trackme/10067} from list [] with 0 entries
02-18 13:16:45.943: V/ActivityManager(201): Removing app ProcessRecord{408e7ae8 0:com.example.trackme/10067} from list [] with 0 entries
02-18 13:16:45.944: V/ActivityManager(201): Removing app ProcessRecord{408e7ae8 0:com.example.trackme/10067} from history with 10 entries
02-18 13:16:45.944: V/ActivityManager(201): Record #9 HistoryRecord{4093d3a0 com.android.settings/.ManageApplications}: app=ProcessRecord{40c1f9e8 26810:com.android.settings/1000}
02-18 13:16:45.944: V/ActivityManager(201): Record #8 HistoryRecord{40adb610 com.android.settings/.ApplicationSettings}: app=ProcessRecord{40c1f9e8 26810:com.android.settings/1000}
02-18 13:16:45.944: V/ActivityManager(201): Record #7 HistoryRecord{409808e8 com.android.settings/.SettingsTabActivity}: app=ProcessRecord{40c1f9e8 26810:com.android.settings/1000}
02-18 13:16:45.944: V/ActivityManager(201): Record #6 HistoryRecord{40875438 com.android.mlabs/.Launcher}: app=ProcessRecord{407ef4e8 23796:android.process.acore/10036}
02-18 13:16:45.944: V/ActivityManager(201): Record #5 HistoryRecord{4077ea58 com.example.trackme/.MainActivity}: app=ProcessRecord{408e7ae8 0:com.example.trackme/10067}
02-18 13:16:45.944: V/ActivityManager(201): Keeping entry, setting app to null
02-18 13:16:45.944: V/ActivityManager(201): Record #4 HistoryRecord{40c103b8 com.android.mms/.ui.ComposeMessageActivity}: app=null
02-18 13:16:45.944: V/ActivityManager(201): Record #3 HistoryRecord{40a540b8 com.android.mms/com.gionee.mms.ui.MmsSmsTabActivity}: app=null
02-18 13:16:45.944: V/ActivityManager(201): Record #2 HistoryRecord{40923ef8 com.android.contacts/.DialtactsActivity}: app=null
02-18 13:16:45.944: V/ActivityManager(201): Record #1 HistoryRecord{40a21258 com.android.calculator2/.Calculator}: app=null
02-18 13:16:45.944: V/ActivityManager(201): Record #0 HistoryRecord{40a61240 com.android.phone/.InCallScreen}: app=ProcessRecord{40881af0 289:com.android.phone/1001}
02-18 13:16:45.944: D/IPCThreadState(201): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x5ba6c8
02-18 13:16:45.947: V/LocationManagerService(201): _removeUpdates: listener = Receiver{409892c0 Listener android.os.BinderProxy@40929d88}mUpdateRecords: {gps=UpdateRecord{40a5e288 mProvider: gps mUid: 10067}, network=UpdateRecord{408e66d0 mProvider: network mUid: 10067}}
02-18 13:16:45.949: D/IPCThreadState(201): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x5ba5d8
02-18 13:16:45.949: D/LocationManagerService(201): removeUpdatesLocked is called provider:receiver: Receiver{409892c0 Listener android.os.BinderProxy@40929d88}mUpdateRecords: {gps=UpdateRecord{40a5e288 mProvider: gps mUid: 10067}, network=UpdateRecord{408e66d0 mProvider: network mUid: 10067}}callingPid: 201ap name:system
02-18 13:16:45.950: D/PowerManagerService(201): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=GpsLocationProvider
02-18 13:16:45.950: I/SurfaceFlinger(201):                                                                              
02-18 13:16:45.950: I/SurfaceFlinger(201): surface flinger stars handleComposing3DStateSetting enter
02-18 13:16:45.950: I/SurfaceFlinger(201): surface flinger stars handleComposing3DStateSetting exit: 0
02-18 13:16:45.952: D/Settings/Provide(201): lookupValue, table secure cache.containsKey location_providers_allowed
02-18 13:16:45.952: D/LocationManagerService(201): isAllowedBySettingsLocked gpsistrue
02-18 13:16:45.952: D/PowerManagerService(201): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=GpsLocationProvider
02-18 13:16:45.952: D/Settings/Provide(201): lookupValue, table secure cache.containsKey location_providers_allowed
02-18 13:16:45.952: D/LocationManagerService(201): isAllowedBySettingsLocked networkistrue
02-18 13:16:45.955: W/GpsLocationProvider(201): Unneeded remove listener for uid 1000
02-18 13:16:45.955: D/IPCThreadState(201): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x20ce78
02-18 13:16:45.957: D/androidNlpServiceThread(280): adding listener com.google.android.location.internal.client.NetworkLocationClient$1@40553208 with period 86400
02-18 13:16:45.957: D/androidNetworkLocationListeners(280): Still have listener com.google.android.location.internal.client.NetworkLocationClient$1@40553208
02-18 13:16:45.959: D/PowerManagerService(201): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=NetworkLocationLocator
02-18 13:16:45.960: D/GpsLocationProvider(201): stopNavigating
02-18 13:16:45.961: D/WifiService(201): acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NetworkLocationLocator type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@409c64a0}
02-18 13:16:45.961: D/Settings/Provide(201): lookupValue, table secure cache.containsKey wifi_on
02-18 13:16:45.961: D/WifiService(201): doUpdateWifiState, mDisableByWifiManager=false, wifiEnabled=true
02-18 13:16:45.961: D/Settings/Provide(201): lookupValue, table system cache.containsKey airplane_mode_radios
02-18 13:16:45.961: D/Settings/Provide(201): lookupValue, table system cache.containsKey airplane_mode_on
02-18 13:16:45.962: D/PowerManagerService(201): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=*wifi*
02-18 13:16:45.963: D/WifiService(201): setWifiEnabledBlocking, enable=true, persist=false, uid=1000
02-18 13:16:45.963: D/WifiStateTracker(201): restart, mConnectingSupplicant=false
02-18 13:16:45.964: V/AlarmManager(201): set: Alarm{40936e10 type 2 com.google.android.location}
02-18 13:16:45.965: V/AlarmManager(201): Adding alarm Alarm{40936e10 type 2 com.google.android.location} at 0
02-18 13:16:45.965: V/AlarmManager(201): alarms: 5 type: 2
02-18 13:16:45.965: V/AlarmManager(201): 0: Jan 02 10:10:39 am com.google.android.location
02-18 13:16:45.965: V/AlarmManager(201): 1: Jan 02 10:14:56 am com.google.android.gsf
02-18 13:16:45.965: V/AlarmManager(201): 2: Jan 02 10:30:33 am com.google.android.apps.maps
02-18 13:16:45.965: V/AlarmManager(201): 3: Jan 02 11:52:19 am com.google.android.apps.maps
02-18 13:16:45.965: V/AlarmManager(201): 4: Dec 15 06:01:30 am com.google.android.apps.maps
02-18 13:16:45.965: V/AlarmManager(201): Native set alarm :Alarm{40936e10 type 2 com.google.android.location}
02-18 13:16:45.966: E/TelephonyManager(280): getDefaultSim is sim1
```

I have used  AsyncTask while sending Data to the server and I am doing my GPS Activity in Service Methods .I dont knw why the WindowManager is stopping my GPS in app. I saw some post related to the ANR issue but in my logcat there is no ANR generated. My activity are responding properly , I am doing all heavy work in background still this is happening .

I have Seen in the logcat WindowManager WIN Death Signal is issuing due to that my GPS is getting Stopped.I am unable to find how to Fix this issue.

Someone can tell me the reason and show me the solve?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing, you cannot instantiate a `Service` like you are doing here:

```
LocationListener mlocListener=new MyLocationListener("", "");
```

`Service` is an Android component and Android components are instantiated by the Android framework. To start a `Service` you need to call `startService()`. Since you obviously want to pass some parameters to your `Service`, you can put them in the `Intent` that you pass to `startService()`.

Don't provide any constructor for the `Service`. Android will do this.

Read up on the lifecycle of `Service` in the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)